# In dart language, can a class be used as a parameter of a method？

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart language, can a class be used as a parameter of a method？

```
class ClipWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ClipWidget({Key key, this.dataItem}) : super(key: key);
  final Map dataItem;
  Map clipColors = {'0': 0xFFFB6F6C, '1': 0xFFFFA73A, '2': 0xFF41D0CA};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Adapt.px(40),
      width: Adapt.px(120),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(clipColors[dataItem['status']]),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      child: Text(
        dataItem['title'],
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: Adapt.px(20),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Color(0xFF303030)),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: Adapt.px(10)),
    );
  }
}

 mapWidget({List data}) {
    // print(data);
    List widgetArr = [];
    for (var item in data) {
      widgetArr.add(ClipWidget(dataItem: item));
    }
    return widgetArr;
  }
```

What should I do if I want ClipWidget as a parameter of the mapWidget method？

Comment: Yes, you can pass the ClipWidget as a parameter. There's something that's it's not working in your code?

Comment: mapWidget({List data,T c}) {
    // print(data);
    List widgetArr = [];
    for (var item in data) {
      widgetArr.add(c(dataItem: item));
    }
    return widgetArr;
  }.      errorr: c The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Comment: Why are you passing a generic type (T) instead of just ClipWidget as a parameter like this `mapWidget({List data, ClipWidget c})` ?

Comment: I found that dart has no class data type and cannot be a(Class<T> t) like java, thank you